# SVG, why can :hover change the stroke-width but not the stroke-color?

Tags: css, svg

Why, in this SVG, can I change the stroke-width on hover, but not the stroke-color?

The problem is clearly presented in the snippet below.

The `stroke-width:5;` is seeing applied to all elements in the `<g id="HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC">`, while the   `stroke:blue;` is seemingly just not applied to any.

## **MWE** SNIPPET

```css
#LEGEND_ABC{
  cursor:pointer;
}
#LEFTTICKBOX_ABC{
  stroke:black;
}
#COLOUREDBOX_ABC{
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
}
#HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC:hover{
  fill:#0000EE;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke:blue;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="500"
  height="70"
  viewBox="-15 -45 500 70">

<g id="LEGEND_ABC">
<g id="HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC">
<rect id="LEFTTICKBOX_ABC"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="COLOUREDBOX_ABC"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="TEXT_ABC"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Color me (why are the rectangles not being stroked blue?)
</text>
</g>
</g>
<defs id="DEFINITIONS">
<rect id="RECTANGLE_YELLOW"
  width="42.5"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="LEGENDBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="25"
  height="25">
</rect>
</defs>
</svg>
```

What I would like, is the whole contents of `<g id="HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC">` being stroked blue on hovering over the group, regardless of what stroke-colors the individual objects have *before* hovering over the group.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado How would I achieve the desired outcome then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be more spesific...  `#HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC:hover #COLOUREDBOX_ABC`

```css
#LEGEND_ABC{
  cursor:pointer;
}
#LEFTTICKBOX_ABC{
  stroke:black;
}
#COLOUREDBOX_ABC{
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
}
#HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC:hover{
  fill:#0000EE;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke:blue;
}
#HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC:hover #COLOUREDBOX_ABC{
  fill:#0000EE;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke:blue;
}
#HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC:hover #LEFTTICKBOX_ABC{
  fill:#0000EE;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke:blue;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="500"
  height="70"
  viewBox="-15 -45 500 70">

<g id="LEGEND_ABC">
<g id="HOVERME_LEGEND_ABC">
<rect id="LEFTTICKBOX_ABC"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="COLOUREDBOX_ABC"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="TEXT_ABC"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Color me (why are the rectangles not being stroked blue?)
</text>
</g>
</g>
<defs id="DEFINITIONS">
<rect id="RECTANGLE_YELLOW"
  width="42.5"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="LEGENDBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="25"
  height="25">
</rect>
</defs>
</svg>
```